# Transcrição da semivogal 'i' é /y/ ou /j/?

Tags: fonética

Encontrei diferença entre dois sites que explicam a transcrição do fonema da semivogal 'i', um site ditou como /y/ e outro como /j/. O que eu pensei no caso do /j/ que na verdade não seria a letra jota mas um i com perna curvada representando a curva que a própria pronúncia faz, isso faz sentido? De qualquer forma, por que essa diferença?

No [site portugues](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/classificacao-dos-fonemas-digrafos-.html#:%7E:text=Semivogais%3A%20s%C3%A3o%20os%20fonemas%20que,u%2F%20%C3%A1tonos%20funcionam%20como%20semivogais) está como /y/.

Mas no [dicionário michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/escolar-ingles/transcricao-fonetica-do-portugues/) de transcrição fonética eles colocam como /j/.

Comment: As duas formas estão corretas. A forma /j/ segue o AFI (Alfabeto Fonético Internacional) e a outra não.

Answer (score 4):

É comum que se use o /y/ para este fonema, porque é mais intuitivo aos falantes. Quando se usa /j/ é um reflexo do Alfabeto Fonético Internacional, que usa [j] para representar a semivogal em questão.